# Django_tables2 How to identify each table when using MultiTableMixin in Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I am trying to render two seperate tables on a different location in a Django template. However, the official documentation only shows how to render the tables in a loop:

```py
{% for table in tables %}
    {% render_table table %}
{% endfor %}
```

This works, however, I want to render a table based on a identifier(such as name). The following code does this, but it doesn't make it clear what table is being rendered:

```py
{% render_table tables.0%}
```

Something among the lines of:

```py
{% render_table tables.newstable %}
```

would be ideal.

I've had slight succes by removing the MultiTableMixin class, then rendering the tables using get_context_data(), however, this breaks pagination.

```py
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TeamHomeTest, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        team_id = self.kwargs['teamid']
        team = Tmteams.objects.get(teamid=team_id)
        q1 = Tmteamsusers.objects.all().filter(teamid=team_id)

        category_ids = []

        categories = nwscategory.objects.all().filter(teamId=team_id)

        for cat in categories:
            category_ids.append(cat.categoryid)

        q2 = nwseditor.objects.filter(categorie_id__in=category_ids)

        team_member_list_table = TeamMemberListTable(q1)
        team_news_list_table = TeamNewsTable(q2)

        context['table1'] = team_member_list_table
        context['table2'] = team_news_list_table
        context['team'] = team
        self.tables=[context['table1'], context['table2']]

        return context
```

My current get_tables() method looks like this:

```py
    def get_tables(self):
        team_id = self.kwargs['teamid']
        q1 = Tmteamsusers.objects.all().filter(teamid=team_id)

        category_ids = []

        categories = nwscategory.objects.all().filter(teamId=team_id)

        for cat in categories:
            category_ids.append(cat.categoryid)

        q2 = nwseditor.objects.filter(categorie_id__in=category_ids)

        table1 = TeamMemberListTable(q1)
        table1.name = "test"

        tables = [
            table1,
            TeamNewsTable(q2)
        ]

        return tables
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your template you can render it as:

```
{% render_table table1 %}
{% render_table table2 %}
```

So you can actually name the table anything you want. It does not have to be table1, table2, ...

Just make sure that the names match you assignment in the get_context_data.

Eg:

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TeamHomeTest, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        team_id = self.kwargs['teamid']
        team = Tmteams.objects.get(teamid=team_id)
        q1 = Tmteamsusers.objects.all().filter(teamid=team_id)

        category_ids = []

        categories = nwscategory.objects.all().filter(teamId=team_id)

        for cat in categories:
            category_ids.append(cat.categoryid)

        q2 = nwseditor.objects.filter(categorie_id__in=category_ids)

        team_member_list_table = TeamMemberListTable(q1)
        team_news_list_table = TeamNewsTable(q2)

        context['table_team_member'] = team_member_list_table
        context['table_team_news'] = team_news_list_table
        context['team'] = team
        self.tables=[context['table_team_member'], context['table_team_news']]

        return context
```

HTML:

```
{% render_table table_team_member %}
{% render_table table_team_news %}
```

Hope this helps